# Reversible but not symmetrical lower plate in seatpost

Tags: seatpost

I have an old seatpost that was removed from its original bike quite some time ago, now I want to use it in another bike, but I don't know if the lower plate should be positioned so it extends behind the top plate or so it extends in front of the top plate.  Pictures will describe it better.  Here the bottom plate is positioned so it extends toward the back of the bike:

[image: bottom plate positioned so it extends toward the back of the bike]

And here the plate is flipped around so it extends toward the front of the bike:

[image]

I can't remember how I had it positioned when I was actually using it.  Does it matter which way it's set?  If so, which is the right way?

Comment: Whichever way works on the seat rails.

Comment: Do you tend to ride with a forward/crouched posture, or a more upright posture ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some Ritchey seat posts have this. They call it

“Reversible clamp for greater fore/aft adjustability”

The correct orientation depends on your fore/aft position. If you are more or less in the middle it shouldn’t matter.

Answer (score 4):

Since neither position offers a clamping advantage I would say it doesn't matter. The only difference I can see is the position in the top/first photo might allow the saddle to be set slightly more forward. The lower/bottom photo position might allow the saddle to be slightly more to the rear.

Comment: perhaps to avoid issues like this?: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/56205/saddle-rail-breaks-often

Answer (score 1):

Is there an arrow molded on the part anywhere? That would tell you. If not, I would put the extending lower tab forwards to give better support for the forwards saddle rails.